# Плагин tickets не работает в MODX Revo, почему?

Tags: cms, modx, плагин, revo, комментарии

знатокам.

Очередной вопрос по MODX Revo.
Понадобилась система комментирования на сайте и установил плагин tickets 1.9.4 последний.
Вместе с ним установился и Jevix (при установке "тикетс" был предложен выбор перезаписать Чанки тикетса, хз зачем и почему, но выбрал ничего не перезаписывать). Настроил в "контроль доступа" к группе users (ранее созданную) доступ к тикетсу. Все ок, вывожу тикетс в шаблоне так

```
[[!TicketComments? &allowGuest=`0` // гостям не нужно видеть форму]]
```

Но, появляется сама форма комментирования, оставляю коммент, нажимаю "написать" кнопку, страница перезагружается (хз должна ли или должен Ajax отрабатывать) и комента нет, в админке его тоже нет. В инете прочитал что почти у каждого такая проблема, кто-то знает как вылечить?

Ошибок никаких не заметил, **jquery** библиотека подключена внизу сайта, пробовал и в **head**, и отключать, не помогает. Сам Тикет не добавляет никакой js файл (вроде бы, по крайней мере библиотеку точно нет). 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: google библиотека jQuery самая последняя подключена перед </body>

Comment: У меня схожая проблема. Поставил tickets компонент, а редактировать в админке тикеты невозможно. Права доступа настроил, а результата ноль. Не знаю даже в чем проблема.

Answer (score 0):

В общем, так и не нашел ответ на свой вопрос. Более того, куча народу имеют такие же траблы с этим плагином, но ответ никто не дал либо никто не разобрался.  Мучаться дальше не стал, удалил его к чертям собачим и появились ошибки в системе, удалились все ресурсы и еще много геморроя, спасибо Боже, что был бэкап. В общем ставьте сие компонент на свое усмотрение.

```
Но я не советую.
```

Лучше попробовать аналоги (**quip, modxTalks**...) Что, существуют только 3-4 плагина системы комментов для modx, серьезно?

Answer (score 0):

Все знатоки(и создатель) сего плагина "сидят" на modx.pro, советовал бы вам там задать этот вопрос.

По комментариях кроме указанных там же можно найти: https://modstore.pro/packages/tag/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8